# RestSharp deserializes an object property incorrectly

Tags: c#, restsharp

I developed an API method that is called from other C# method.

I defined this class:

```
public class ApiResult
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public object? data { get; set; }
}
```

Note the `data` property.

Then I do this:

```
public static async Task<ApiResult?> GetAsync(string baseUrl, string endpoint)
{
    using var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
    var request = new RestRequest(endpoint, Method.Get);
    var response = await client.ExecuteAsync<ApiResult>(request);
    return response.Data;  // ApiResult instance is returned
}
```

When I construct the `ApiResult` object, I populate `data` property with an instance of a class called `Persona`.

Finally I can see that `response.Data` contains this object:

```
response.data
{Modules.Integration.ApiModels.ApiResult}
    data: ValueKind = Object : "{"tipoDocumentoId":3,"centroCostoId":0,"centroCostoNombre":"","departamentoId":0,"departamentoNombre":"","cargoId":0,"cargoNombre":"","codigo":11727935,"nombres":"Jaime","apellidos":"Stuardo","email":null,"fechaNacimiento":null,"sexo":"M","telefono":null,"tarjeta":null,"patente":null,"codigoInterno":null,"fechaContrato":null,"nombreFoto":null,"ssn":"117279359","ssnFormateado":"11.727.935-9","id":2,"estaVigente":true,"fechaCreacion":"2023-05-24T09:20:57.2","fechaActualizacion":null}"
    message: ""
    success: true
```

See the `ApiResult.data` property, which contains the `Persona` instance but not as an intance of the `Persona` object but a JSON object.

How can I make RestSharp to deserialize the JSON object into the actual object instance?

EDIT:

Here is what I expect following by what I am receiving:

```
expectedResult
{Modules.Integration.ApiModels.ApiResult}
    data: {Modules.Integration.ApiModels.Persona}
    message: ""
    success: true
actualResult
{Modules.Integration.ApiModels.ApiResult}
    data: ValueKind = Object : "{"tipoDocumentoId":3,"centroCostoId":0,"centroCostoNombre":"","departamentoId":0,"departamentoNombre":"","cargoId":0,"cargoNombre":"","codigo":11727935,"nombres":"Jaime","apellidos":"Stuardo","email":null,"fechaNacimiento":null,"sexo":"M","telefono":null,"tarjeta":null,"patente":null,"codigoInterno":null,"fechaContrato":null,"nombreFoto":null,"ssn":"117279359","ssnFormateado":"11.727.935-9","id":2,"estaVigente":true,"fechaCreacion":"2023-05-24T09:20:57.2","fechaActualizacion":null}"
    message: ""
    success: true
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the JSON content, that was generated during the serialization process. Is it acceptable to change how the JSON content is generated (namely the type name handling with `"$type":` stuff). Is it known on the receiving end what type is expected, specially when the `"$type"` property is missing? Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @Progman I have edited the question with what I expect versus what I am receiving. Thanks.

Comment: You have not added any requested information or answered questions I asked. Please [edit] your question to include these information.

Comment: @Progman Then I didn't understand what you asked me for. You wrote: "Please edit your question to include the JSON content". I have edited the question and included the JSON content. Please explain what you need exactly.

Comment: Check other resources like https://json.org/example.html on how JSON data looks like. It might be important to see if any `"$type"` data is available or not in your JSON data you send between your components/servers. Also, the other requested information are still missing.

Comment: @Program I know how JSON looks like, but it seems you did not read that the question is about RestSharp. All JSON stuff is made inside of it. I only work with object instances. The only JSON I am seeing is that I have already written: `"{"tipoDocumentoId":3,"centroCostoId":0,"centroCostoNombre":"","...... `. That is an object in JSON notation. That is my problem. I need RestSharp to deserialize that JSON into the actual object.

Comment: Can you change the JSON data that is being send by the server? Do you know the expected type of the object in the `Data` property when you call your method in your code?

Comment: @Program I can deserialize the JSON object by myself, but the idea of this is to be done by RestSharp. If I call `result.data.GetType()` I can check that the returned property is of type JsonElement. The API is returning the correct object instance `Persona`, however RestSharp is sending it to the API client as a JsonElement. I am looking for a way to avoid that behaviour. I had used TinyRest.Client before with which I did not have this kind of problem, but it seems TinyRest.Client project was abandoned since 2020 because it is not compatible with .NET 7 and no more updates have been made.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I have deserialized that object by myself.

I created this extension method:

```
    public static T? ToObject<T>(this object? o)
    {
        if (o is null || !(o is JsonElement))
            return default;

        return ((JsonElement)o).Deserialize<T>();
    }
```

And then, I called it this way:

```
var persona = RestConnection.Get<ApiResult>(baseUrl, string.Format(endpoint, ssn))?.data.ToObject<Persona>();
```

`RestConnection` is a class that encapsulates `RestSharp` calls.